# How to use i64 with Insertable using Diesel

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

How do I use `i64`/`u64` with Diesel?

Do I really need to implement the `diesel::Expression` trait for the primitive type?

Here is my code.

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
...
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["sqlite", "numeric"] }
```

`migration/up.sql`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE books (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  size INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

`schema.rs`:

```rust
table! {
    books (id) {
        id -> Integer,
        size -> Integer,
    }
}
```

sources:

```rust
use crate::schema::books;

#[derive(Insertable, Queryable)]
#[table_name="books"]
pub struct BookRecord {
    pub id: Id,
    pub size: i64,
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i64: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib/models/book.rs:4:10
  |
4 | #[derive(Insertable, Queryable)]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `i64`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Integer>` for `i64`
  = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`i64` corresponds to `BigInt`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.5/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSql.html#impl-FromSql%3CBigInt%2C%20Sqlite%3E-for-i64) and [`i32` corresponds to `Integer`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.5/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSql.html#impl-FromSql%3CInteger%2C%20Sqlite%3E-for-i32). Either change your schema to use `BigInt`, or change your numbers to `i32`.